# How do I chown files/folders synced with rsync-auto?

Tags: vagrant

Using vagrant is there anyway to specify an rsynced user and have it chown the files to a specific user and group? In my Vagrant file I have the following:

```
  config.vm.synced_folder "app/code", "/var/www/shop/app/code", type: "rsync"
  config.vm.synced_folder "app/design/frontend", "/var/www/shop/app/design/frontend", type: "rsync"
  config.vm.synced_folder "pub", "/var/www/shop/pub", type: "rsync"
```

When I run `vagrant rsync-auto` the permissions for the sync'ed folder are `root:root`, but I need the owner and group set to `magento:www-data`.

Is there any way to do this?